# Как архивировать выделенные файлы

Tags: linux, unix, tar

Добрый день.
В папку apache2 есть файлы хочу архивировать все папки кроме logs
С помощью команды 
tar -cvjf newfile.tar.bz2 ./apache2 могу архивировать все, но как мне исключить папку logs? ([image: Принт скрин выложил])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здравствуйте.

```
tar -cvjf newfile.tar.bz2 ./apache2 --exclude=./apache2/logs
```

Подробнее в man tar.

Comment: Спасибо. Получилось